# I want to print tabulated data in row but it is printing in column

Tags: python, tabulate

here is what I tried

```
for book in books:
    print (tabulate(book, headers=["ID", "Title", "Author", "Pub_year", "available", "Shelf Place"]))
```

the output is

```
1
ID    Title    Author    Pub_year    available    Shelf Place
----  -------  --------  ----------  -----------  -------------
0     0        0         0           1
P     y        t         h           o            n
J     i        m                     c            a
2     0        2         0
1     2
2     0        B         2
```

Comment: maybe you should send `books` directly ot `tabulate`. it may need list of rows (even every row is list of items) but you send single row and it treats every string in this row as list of items and it may display every char as separated value. And if you really want to display single row then use list `[book]` instead of `book`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what you have in `books` so I guess all problem is that `tabulate` needs list of rows (and every row has to be list of items) but you send single row and it threads every string in this list as list of items (so it treads every char as separated item).

If you want to display all books then you should use directly `books` instead of loop with `book`

And if you want to display every `book` in separated table then use list `[book]` instead of `book`

```
from tabulate import tabulate

books = [
    ['1','Title 1','Author 1','2009', True, '9.99'],
    ['2','Title 2','Author 2','2010', True, '19.99'],
    ['3','Title 3','Author 3','2011', True, '29.99'],
]

print(tabulate(books, headers=["ID", "Title", "Author", "Pub_year", "available", "Shelf Place"]))
print('=================')

for book in books:
    print(tabulate([book], headers=["ID", "Title", "Author", "Pub_year", "available", "Shelf Place"]))
    print('=================')
```

Result:

```
  ID  Title    Author      Pub_year  available      Shelf Place
----  -------  --------  ----------  -----------  -------------
   1  Title 1  Author 1        2009  True                  9.99
   2  Title 2  Author 2        2010  True                 19.99
   3  Title 3  Author 3        2011  True                 29.99
=================
  ID  Title    Author      Pub_year  available      Shelf Place
----  -------  --------  ----------  -----------  -------------
   1  Title 1  Author 1        2009  True                  9.99
=================
  ID  Title    Author      Pub_year  available      Shelf Place
----  -------  --------  ----------  -----------  -------------
   2  Title 2  Author 2        2010  True                 19.99
=================
  ID  Title    Author      Pub_year  available      Shelf Place
----  -------  --------  ----------  -----------  -------------
   3  Title 3  Author 3        2011  True                 29.99
=================
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use headers at the first line in the row
you can use a different approach.
Use that `iterable` as showindex=<your_list>

I've needed the same solution and found it in the tabulates documentation.

> By default, only pandas.DataFrame tables have an additional column
> called row index. To add a similar column to any other type of table,
> pass showindex="always" or showindex=True argument to tabulate(). To
> suppress row indices for all types of data, pass showindex="never" or
> showindex=False. To add a custom row index column, pass
> showindex=rowIDs, where rowIDs is some iterable:

```
heads = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
data= [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
row_index= ["first", "second"]
print(tabulate(data, headers=heads, showindex=row_index))
```

and mind that the size of the data (as in rows) must equal to index's size.